# Python Crawling- TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Tags: python, loops, web-crawler, iterable

Here is my code right now:

```
front_deeplink = ("http://www.jsox.de")
Spider = 20
Region = 7236


def trade_spider(max_pages):
for reg in Region:
    page = 0
    while page <= max_pages:
        page += 1
        r = requests.get("http://www.jsox.de/affiliatesearch.aspx?&regionid=" + str(reg) + "&pid=" + str(page))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

        g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "gridHeadOuter productInfoOuter"})

        for item in g_data:
            Header = item.find_all("div", {"class": "offerInto"})
            Header_final = (Header[0].contents[0].text.strip())
            price = item.find_all("strong", {"class": "priceBig priceBlock"})
            Price_final = (price[0].text.strip())
            Deeplink = item.find_all("a")
            for t in set(t.get("href") for t in Deeplink):        
                Deeplink_final = (str(front_deeplink) + t)

            print("Header: " + Header_final + " | " + "Price: " + Price_final[:-1] + " | " + "Deeplink: " + Deeplink_final)

trade_spider(int(Spider))
```

However, I keep getting the error message:

```
for reg in Region:
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

when I try and run this.

What am I doing wrong?

Can anyone help me with that? Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: You have defined `Region = 7236`, which is an `int`, so, like the error says, you cannot iterate over it.

Comment: What are you trying to do? what are you supposed to do with the number `7236`?

Comment: 7236 is simpy a number for a region, e.g Rome

Comment: OK, then what were you expecting to do with `for reg in 7236` if you _know_ that `7236` is the value of `Region`?

Comment: Had no clue that numbers are not iterable.

Comment: Well, but what were you trying to do then? go from `0` to `7236`? or go through each one of the digits (7, 2, 3, 6)? either can be easily implemented, but we're still in the dark on what you really, really meant to do.

Comment: I simply wanted to crawl the prices, header and deeplink of a particular city, e.g. Rome which has the RegionID = 7236 and so on. Does it make clear?:)

Comment: But the only point where you use `reg` is to construct the url, you don't need a loop for that. Delete the line with the first `for` loop and pass `reg` as parameter. And if this solves your problem, don't forget to accept the correct answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **range()** or **xrange()**, which receive an int and produce an iterable.

Answer (score 3):

In your code you have this declaration:

```
Region = 7236
```

Then, you try to do this:

```
for reg in Region:
```

Clearly, a `Region` is *just a number*, you can't iterate over it as you would, say, iterate over a list. Use `for` to traverse lists, or other iterable objects - numbers are simply not iterable.